# S3 integration testing

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, integration-testing

I need to setup an integration test to:

1. Save a record to s3.
2. Find the saved data location in dynamo db.
3. Publish a message to send to a downstream system queue
4. I also have to setup a s3 client.

I haven't tried anything because I am stuck on this.